# Error when tried to allocate bytes

Tags: php, pdo

i convert a old system to use PDO. 
EDIT: Forgot to add the error: 
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted

The problem i faced here is this function:

The original code:

```
function visitors_get_data() {
   // select
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT `ip`, `value` FROM `visitors`");
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $data[] = $row;
   }
   if (isset($data)) return $data;
      else return false;
   }
```

Here is my edit:

```
function visitors_get_data() {
   $dbc1 = new Db();
   // select
   $sth = $dbc1->PDOPrepare("SELECT `ip`, `value` FROM `visitors`");
   $sth->execute();
   $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

       while ($row = $result) {
          $data[] = $row;
       }
       if (isset($data)) return $data;
        else return false;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You want to move the assignment for `$result` into your while statement definition. You're currently always assigning the same value to `$row` - `$result` never changes

Comment: Do you have an example? Sorry for being pain in the ass, just so new at this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with these lines:

```
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while ($row = $result) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

You're assigning `$result`, and then using that value in your while loop. What is happening is that you're then assigning `$row` with the same value over and over, until you run out of memory.

To fix it, you just need to move the assignments:

```
while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

That will loop through the database, assigning each row into `$data`.

You can also pull back everything in one go, as your code currently does, using `fetchAll`

```
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

In that case, everything is already assigned to `$result`, so you don't need the while loop at all. If you have a look at the [man page](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php), you can see the format that `fetchAll` returns you data - it might not be exactly what you're expecting.